# Try/catch block not handling the error that occurs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, try-catch, angularfire

This `try catch` block doesn't seem to catch the error that occurs, which is strange, considering I have a similar `try catch` block for the registration part of the site. This handles the login. The error occurs at the third line `email: $scope.authInfo.email` and throws this error:

```
Error: Firebase.authWithPassword failed: First argument must contain the key "email" with type "string"
```

This occurs when the email format is wrong, for example `test@`. So when it is I want an error message to be set in the `catch` block.

Does anyone know why this `try catch` isn't working?

```
try {
    $scope.syncAuth.$authWithPassword({
        email: $scope.authInfo.email,
        password: $scope.authInfo.password
    }).then(function(authData) {
        $scope.isSuccessful = true;
        $scope.success = 'You have successfully logged in - Redirecting...';
        $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
        $timeout($scope.redirectUser, 3000);
    }).catch(function(error) {

        switch (error.code) {

            case 'INVALID_USER': $scope.errors.push('The email you have entered is not a registered user.'); 
                                break;

            case 'INVALID_PASSWORD': $scope.errors.push('Invalid password.'); 
                                break;
        }
    });
}
catch (err) {
    $scope.errors.push('Invalid email format.')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [source code here](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/b8c5843efeac7e3003b1d8fe845ef12a1b2dddc9/src/FirebaseAuth.js#L122) of `$authWithPassword` method. As you can see if error will be thrown - firebase will return rejected promise. So you can handle your error in the promise catch block:

```
$scope.syncAuth.$authWithPassword({
    email: $scope.authInfo.email,
    password: $scope.authInfo.password
})
.catch(function(error) {
    switch (error.code) {
        case 'INVALID_USER': 
            $scope.errors.push('The email you have entered is not a registered user.');
            break;
        case 'INVALID_PASSWORD': 
            $scope.errors.push('Invalid password.');
            break;
        default:
            $scope.errors.push('Invalid email format.')
    }
    throw error;
})
.then(function(authData) {
    $scope.isSuccessful = true;
    $scope.success = 'You have successfully logged in - Redirecting...';
    $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
    $timeout($scope.redirectUser, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Proper answer would be to delete the last .catch and put the switch in the first catch. Other than that it works. Do you know why I have to put the .catch before the then? On Firebase's website they use the .then before.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Yeah, you're right. The truth is I didn't read your question completely. Just saw the cause or your trouble and answered at the same time. Sorry.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz But remember - you must throw an error in that `catch block`. If you do not do this - error will be handled, and `then block` will be invoked.